# graphQLHttpClient Connection failure on Android, works on Windows

Tags: graphql, maui

I have a Maui app which works just fine when I run it with as a Windows Machine, but switching to Android I get a connection failure.  Same dev machine, same back-end server. It is running on localhost port 5001.

According to the server logs, it is not even hitting the Endpoint to submit the query.  Endpoint is the same.  Just upgraded to .Net 8.  Not sure if this was a problem on .Net 7 as I had only been working with the Windows machines.  I have included the code where the failure happens.

```
private static async Task<(RootObject obj, string rtnMsg)> GetDocumentAsync(string iQuery)
{
    RootObject obj = null;
    string rtnMsg = "";
    var graphQLOptions = new GraphQLHttpClientOptions
    {
        EndPoint = new Uri($"{Url}/graphql", UriKind.Absolute)
    };

    var graphQLHttpClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(graphQLOptions, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

    var documentRequest = new GraphQLRequest { Query = iQuery };

    try
    {
        var graphQLResponse = await graphQLHttpClient.SendQueryAsync<RootObject>(documentRequest);
        Debug.Print("");
        return (graphQLResponse.Data,"");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        rtnMsg = ex.Message + " [ErpPart.GetDocumentAsync]";
        Debug.Print(ex.Message);
        return (obj,rtnMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use localhost.  There are many, many existing questions that address this

Comment: I remember something like that earlier on Android in my testing but I thought it was resolved .. guess not as a ngrok connection worked.

Comment: `localhost` refers to the current device, which means that Android will try to connect to itself.  If you want it to connect to a server, use the FQDN or IP of the server.  If you are using an emulator, there are numerous articles about setting up local networking for the emulator.  Finally, be sure that your server can accept remote requests